# External hard disk files disappeared after connected to dissimilar hardware PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I know a hard disk (or ssd) may not work in dissimilar hardware, in different PCs. But I just wanted to use the disk to the new PC as a test quickly, so just replaced the disk to new desktop PC from old laptop one. And, it worked. Firstly its graphic was weird but fixed automatically in no time. Then I used the machine for a while. While that time, I use some software and Adobe after effects, and exported a video files to an external hard disk. Yes, definitely saved it. And after a while I turned off the desktop, and replaced the disk. Then, I booted the desktop with an other SSD (this is mainly used one actually) connected to the external hard disk, then I tried to check the video files I saved. And, I noticed the folder and files I created while using the laptop disk, were nowhere to be found. Seems they are disappeared. This is first time I lost some files from hard disk this clearly. Is that really possible to lose files actually saved? Does this mean the hard disk rolled back or something? What is happening? What was wrong with me? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify your OS. I assume Windows 10 but could be very different. What sort of search have you done? Tell us. People lose files all the time, forgetting names or locations.The files are there but cannot be found.

Comment: If this is the system drive, then you might be missing some driver(s).

Comment: CharlesKenyon, "forgetting names or locations" is nearly impossible to me. The only available hard disk was the only one and I can remember clearly where is was. Also I use Everything software to search files from all the hard disks, it should be found by it, but nowhere to be found. I'm almost sure the files gone, 
also, yes, the OS it's Windows 10. Windows 10 to Windows 10.

Comment: harrymc, losing files on system drive (like C:) by doing such stuff is understandable, I think. but as I said, surprisingly it's external hard disk, no windows system files. so I'm quite surprised.

Answer (score 0):

> so just replaced the disk to new desktop PC from old laptop one. And,
> it worked.

Moving operating drives from one computer to another is not supported.  Different BIOS, and different drivers.  You really cannot switch drives between computers reliably.

So the loss of files is likely the result of the above differences.

Also, depending on the OS, activation (lack of it) on different hardware could be a problem.

You would need to recover the files from a backup or older versions.

Comment: a backup or older versions, means software like Recuva you mean? Also, my main concern here is, "Is that really possible to lose files on *external hard disks* ?" Also I didn't write about this but the system disk was no data damage. The only external hard disk data lost. So I'm really confused

Comment: "so just replaced the disk to new desktop PC from old laptop one."   <-- You indicated you installed the disk as an operating system disk and that caused numerous issues. Yes it is confusing.